# Who has ILNumerics community edition?

Tags: .net, ilnumerics

Now,the ILNumerics is a commercial version now. but it has a community edition before.where can I get a open-source community edition ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is the community edition : https://github.com/mvarie/ILNumerics (LGP License) .